# How to add arbitrary log data to MongoDB logs from client?

Tags: mongodb, web-services, database-performance

I have a node.js web application connecting to MongoDB for which I want to profile DB performance. Each request received by the application is assigned a request-id and can cause multiple queries to be sent to MongoDB. I want to see this request-id value in each log line in MongoDB. Is there a way to do this? I would like to avoid adding always-true fields to each query like `"req<id>": null` because I suspect this may affect performance.

The docs reference a feature similar to this called `Client Data` at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/ however this appears to be sent once per connection, and I'm looking for client data that changes multiple times even on the same single connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cursor.comment()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.comment/#cursor.comment) to record the request ID value into the log messages.